# Differences: "in some recent years" vs "in recent years"

Tags: differences

I can't distinguish the differences. When(how) to use them, and context?

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In recent years" implies all recent years, for example, something happened in 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, and 2013. "In some recent years" suggests that it happened in some but not others, for example, 2007, 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2013.